# User list for mod-auth-openidc

Tags: apache, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc, google-openidconnect

I have set-up openidc for apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from the [read me](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/README.md). Everything is running smoothly (I think) EXCEPT I can't find any documentation for how to configure an allowed user (white) list.

I have a very small stable user list so I would like to use something simple like a txt file. If anyone can point me toward some documentation or an example it would be greatly appreciated

Below is a except of my apache config file. I would like something similar to the Require statement below

```
         <Location />
              AuthType openid-connect
              Require user <email1>@gmail.com <email2>@gmail.com
         </Location>
```

I have tested the log-in using but this doesn't offer much Privacy :)

```
         <Location />
              AuthType openid-connect
              Require valid-user
         </Location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Require claim email:<email1>@gmail.com email:<email2>@gmail.com`. See also: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Authorization#1-mod_auth_openidc

Comment: As a side-note, this does not seem to work in a .htaccess file for me